# What is this React syntax: inputRef?.current?.current

Tags: reactjs

I saw this code snippet in React.

`const selected = document.activeElement === inputRef?.current?.current;`

Does `inputRef?.current?.current` equal `if (inputRef !== undefined && inputRef.current !== undefined) return inputRef.current`

Comment: Relevant documentation: [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: Not equal to `... return inputRef.current` but equal to `... return inputRef.current.current`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the new features for [nodeJS](https://nodejs.org) v14.0 called `Optional Chaining`, it check if the value is `!undefined`

Thus, `inputRef?.current?.current` equals to
`if (inputRef && inputRef.current) return inputRef.current.current`

Please read this interesting [post](https://medium.com/nmc-techblog/new-js-features-in-node-js-v14-0-6d833c7665b6) on medium about the most important new features for NodeJS

Comment: It's not feature of `nodeJS`. It's feature of ES2020 standard. NodeJS just implemented it in their v14. JavaScript runs not only on NodeJS. ;)